# How can i get key, value from this kind of response in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

from the controller side, it sends the data like this,

```
{:room_id=>383, :title=>"111's new appointment", :description=>"new content", :organizer=>"4444 1111", :appointment_id=>"266", :is_owner=>true, :roomtype=>"1", :c
onference_time=>"12.12 10:00 ~ 12.12 23:00", :maximun_users=>"3", :current_user_list=>[#<Client firstname: "4444", lastname: "1111">], :users=>"1 / 3"}
```

I know how to get other data, but my problem is this,

```
:current_user_list=>[#<Client firstname: "4444", lastname: "1111">]
```

how can i get the key and value in here???

```
<% @appointments.each do |appointment| %>
            <%=Rails.logger.debug("**********APPOINTEMTN : : : : : : : ******"+appointment[:current_user_list].to_s)%>
            <% if appointment[:is_owner] %>
            <tr class="roomlist_myrow">

                <td><%=h appointment[:room_id] %></td>
                <td><%=h appointment[:title] %></td>
                <td><%=h get_roomtype_from_room_list().rassoc(appointment[:roomtype])[0] %></td>
                <td><%=h appointment[:users] %></td>
                <td style="color: #a9a9a9"><%=h appointment[:organizer] %></td>
                <td style="color: #3c3c3c"><%=h appointment[:conference_time] %></td>

                <td>
                    <% url = get_appointment_server(appointment[:appointment_id]) %>
                    <%= button_to_function "Enter", "enter_room('#{appointment[:room_id]}','#{url}')"%>
                    <%= link_to ("<button>Modify</button>".html_safe), make_params({ :action => :edit, :id => appointment[:appointment_id] }) %>
                    <%= link_to ("<button>Delete</button>".html_safe), make_params({ :action => :destroy, :id => appointment[:appointment_id] }), 
                                                                                                method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
                </td>
              </tr>
            <%else%>
              <tr class="roomlist_row">

                <td><%=h appointment[:room_id] %></td>
                <td><%=h appointment[:title] %></td>
                <td><%=h get_roomtype_from_room_list().rassoc(appointment[:roomtype])[0] %></td>
                <td><%=h appointment[:users] %></td>
                <td style="color: #a9a9a9"><%=h appointment[:organizer] %></td>
                <td style="color: #3c3c3c"><%=h appointment[:conference_time] %></td>

                <td id="roomlist_notowner_td">
                    <% url = get_appointment_server(appointment[:appointment_id]) %>
                    <%= button_to_function "Enter", "enter_room('#{appointment[:room_id]}','#{url}')"%>

                </td>
              </tr>
            <%end%>

            <% end %>
```

if i print it shows,

```
<%=Rails.logger.debug("**********APPOINTEMTN : : : : : : : ******"+appointment[:current_user_list].to_s)%>
**********APPOINTEMTN : : : : : : : ******#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x4d48880>
```

Any good solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through it:  `appointment[:current_user_list].each do |user|` then print it `user.firstname` or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

If `appointment[:current_user_list]` is an Array obect then you could try these public methods:

> hash.each_key { |key_value_array| block }
>   Iterates over hash, calling the block once for each key, passing the key and value as parameters.

or this

> hash.each { |key,value| block }
>   Iterates over hash, calling the block once for each key, passing the key-value as a two-element array.

Found here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_hashes.htm